# Problema com python no postgres no MAC

Tags: python, postgresql, trigger

Gente, estou testando funções trigger com python no Postgres e estou com problemas quando vou testar no meu Mac. Segue a função:

```
create function sendchange()
returns trigger
as $$
import requests
import json

url = "http://localhost:8080/send"
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

payload = {'source': TD['args'][0], 'table': TD['args'][1], 'data': TD['new']}
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
$$ language plpythonu;
```

E a criação da trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insertteste AFTER INSERT
ON processo FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE sendchange ('application','usuario');
```

Ocorre que, no ambiente windows, a trigger funciona sem problema algum. Porém quando testo no Mac, é lançado o erro:

```
SQL state: 38000
Context: Traceback (most recent call last):
PL/Python function "sendchange", line 2, in <module>
import requests
PL/Python function "sendchange"
```

Não tenho ideia do porque isso esta acontecendo no ambiente linux do Mac. Esse script é para enviar dados do banco para outra aplicação.

Comment: no código de erro, parece que o módulo `requests` não está disponível para o interpretador do python que o Postgresql acessa.

Comment: Esse é o problema, eu instalei o modulo requests, porém a execução do script python a partir do banco não enxerga este modulo. Eu não sei se é necessário fazer mais alguma configuração no ambiente linux para que o plpythonu acesse as dependências. Já testei no ambiente windowns e não tive nenhum problema.